# How can I install highcharts-angular *and* highcharts?

Tags: angular, npm, highcharts

**UPDATE**: problem solved - the package.json file was read-only (see my answer).

---

I have an Angular (7) app, and I'm trying to install Highcharts. I'm following the instructions for highcharts-angular [here](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular).

The instructions [say](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular#installing):

> Get package from NPM in your Angular app:

```
npm install highcharts-angular --save
```

OK, that's fine. But then later in the same section, it says:

> In a component that will be building your Highcharts charts you will need to import Highcharts first, so in system console, while in your Angular app:

```
npm install highcharts --save
```

...and when I do that, npm installs highcharts but *un*installs highcharts-angular!

I also tried installing them the other way around, with the same result - it seems you can only install one at a time.

Clearly I'm doing something wrong - but what?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with statements although I tested it with Angular 6

Comment: I tested it with Angular 7 and it works fine to me.

Comment: @WojciechChmiel: so... any idea why I see this behaviour? Would it be something to do with my package.json or something? Anything I can post to help resolve this?

Comment: you can manually add highcharts and highcharts-angular to your **package.json** instead of installing it through the cli. then you can delete node_modules and then run `npm install`. that should solve the package saving issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow. What I didn't mention in the question - because I didn't think it relevant - is that I'm using VS2017 and (crucially) VSTS (or whatever it's called now) for version control.

Because my project is under version control, the package.json file was read-only. And that meant that npm was loading files for the first package but *not* updating the package.json - then when I then installed the second package, it noticed that the files for the first package were not listed in package.json, so it did some "housekeeping" and removed them. And of course the same would happen for the second package, and so on.

Again, wow.